# `last_comment` is deprecated. Please use `last_description` instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm using ruby on rails and I keep getting this error when using Rake commands. I tried to figure it out by googling and saw some stuff on updating rake or rspec versions causing problems. I tried but it didn't work and I'm not sure why I keep getting the error.

ruby version ruby 2.3.0p0

rails version Rails 4.2.6

rspec-rails 3.0

Comment: I also ran across this, but upgrading from rspec-rails 3.0 and rspec-3.3.0 fixed it for me. If you're using bundle, try `bundle update rspec rspec-rails`. I also was using ruby 2.3.0 and rails 4.2.6

Answer (score 5):

I tried specifying in the gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4.4'
```

and

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.3.0'
```

and after each one I did

```
bundle update
bundle install
```

and neither worked.

I ended up just removing the version part at the end:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

And then did bundle update and it worked. My terminal showed:

```
Using rspec-rails 3.4.2
```

Comment: I updated to `rspec-rails 3.4.2` and the **warning went away**

Answer (score 5):

wspurgin's comment is the best answer. 
I tried doing

> bundle update rspec

and

> bundle update rspec-rails

and also

> bundle update rspec-core

to no avail (ie. it did not get a newer version of the gems).
When I tried specifying the required version 3.4.4 (according to google searches) of rspec-core I got

> rspec-core (~> 3.4.4)
>
> ```
> rspec-rails was resolved to 3.3.3, which depends on
>   rspec-core (~> 3.3.0)
> ```

Therefore by updating rspec and rspec-rails together

> bundle update rspec rspec-rails

It does the trick and gets the new versions.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `bundle update rspec rspec-rails`